# Displaying return value from url to a div on my website using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

please help me i am tying to get the return value and print it within a div if conditions are met.

I get the information from : [Here](http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus)

What i wish to accomplish is to get the value from http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus
and subtract 1 from it and display it on my website.

What i have is:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajax({
url: "https://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus",
method: "GET"})
.done(function(status) {
var value = "Error1";
if(status == 1){
value = "No Loadshedding at the moment";
}
else if(status == 2){
value = "Stage 1 Loadshedding";
}
else if(status == 3){
value = "Stage 2 Loadshedding";
}
else if(status == 4){
value = "Stage 3 Loadshedding";
}
else{
value = "Error";
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML(value);
consol.log(value);
});
});
setInterval(5000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help or way to do this i would greatly appreciate.

Comment: Are you retrieving json file or a string or integer???

Comment: I want to retrieve an integer.

Comment: Your spelling of console is wrong.. can you correct it and check what console gives?

Comment: I checked now but still to no prevail. what i want to do is to just print the number returned from http://loadshedding.eskom.co.za/LoadShedding/GetStatus and subtract 1 and set interval if the number changes to change on my site

Comment: Hey, you added https in url, Try http only...

Comment: just tried still not working i think i need to rewrite the entire code